# Multi-level menu for an FAQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, review

I am making a FAQ that ask you 3 question to give you the correct answer. It works in the same way as this website: [Nokia Lumia FAQ](https://goo.gl/Z90Mtl).

The code works. You have 3 level of content to see depending on the button you press. When a button is pressed on level 1, level 2 and level 3 it will change color so you end with three button that have changed color, its easier to understand in that way you wanted help for Example: *Phone - Andriod - Simcard help.*

Notice that level 1 and level 2 content have much simliar in the JS code, but level 3 is a bit different because there your browser scroll you down when the content is displayed. And also level 3 does have hyperlink instead of button.

I have to manually dublicate part of this JS code for adding new buttons, and i think there can be an easier way. I really appreciate any help.

**Here is the JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// Level 1
function show(sel) {
  var el = $(sel);
  el.fadeToggle();
  $('.showmore-1').not(el).fadeOut("slow");
}

$('.showmore-1').hide();

$('.click-1').click(function(){
    $('.click-1').removeClass('clickcolor')
        $(this).addClass('clickcolor');
});

$('#click-1a').click(function () {
  show('#showmore-1a');
});

$('#click-1b').click(function () {
  show('#showmore-1b');
});

$('#click-1c').click(function () {
  show('#showmore-1c');
});


// Level 2
function show(sel) {
  var el = $(sel);
  el.fadeToggle();
  $('.showmore-2').not(el).fadeOut("slow");
}

$('.showmore-2').hide();

$('.click-2').click(function(){
    $('.click-2').removeClass('clickcolor')
        $(this).addClass('clickcolor');
});

$('#click-2a').click(function () {
  show('#showmore-2a');
});

$('#click-2b').click(function () {
  show('#showmore-2b');
});

$('#click-2c').click(function () {
  show('#showmore-2c');
});

// Level 3
function show(sel) {
  var el = $(sel);
  el.fadeToggle();
  $('.showmore-3').not(el).fadeOut("slow");
}

$('.showmore-3').hide();

$('.click-3').click(function(){
    $('.click-3').removeClass('clickcolortext') //Level 3 display text instead of button to be pressed and therefore another class of color.
    $(this).addClass('clickcolortext');
});

$('#click-3a').click(function () {
  show('#showmore-3a');
  $('html, body').scrollTop($('#showmore-3a').offset().top);
  return false; 
});

$('#click-3b').click(function () {
  show('#showmore-3b');
  $('html, body').scrollTop($('#showmore-3b').offset().top);
  return false; 
});

$('#click-3c').click(function () {
  show('#showmore-3c');
  $('html, body').scrollTop($('#showmore-3c').offset().top);
  return false; 
});

});
enter code here
```

**Here is a part of the HTML**

```
<button class="click-1" id="click-1a">Mobile</button> 
<button class="click-1" id="click-1b">PC</button> 
<button class="click-1" id="click-1c">Tablet</button>

<div id="showmore-1a" class="showmore-1">View content for mobile help</div>
<div id="showmore-1b" class="showmore-1">View content for pc help</div>
<div id="showmore-1c" class="showmore-1">View content for tablet help</div>
enter code here
```

**Here is the CSS**

```
.clickcolor {
    background-color: #4d4d4d !important;
}

.clickcolortext {
    color: #4d4d4d !important;
}
```

Comment: If you have a working code, and you're looking for advice on how to improve the style, codereview.stackexchange.com is a better site.

Comment: Thanks i will check that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a target attribute on buttons:

```
<button class="click-1" id="click-1a" data-target="#showmore-1a">Mobile</button> 
<button class="click-1" id="click-1b" data-target="#showmore-1b">PC</button> 
<button class="click-1" id="click-1c" data-target="#showmore-1c">Tablet</button>
```

JS

```
$('button.click-1').click(function(){
      $('.click-1').removeClass('clickcolor')
      $(this).addClass('clickcolor');
      show($(this).data('target'));
});
```

Comment: That actually worked. Can i somehow shorten or erase the class showmore-1? It only tells that the content should be not displayed. <div id="showmore-1a" class="showmore-1">View content for mobile help</div>
<div id="showmore-1b" class="showmore-1">View content for pc help</div>
<div id="showmore-1c" class="showmore-1">View content for tablet help</div>

Comment: You wrote a target attribute on my button. Im wondering if i can delete the ID attribute on my buttons, because i dont see they do any purpose?

Comment: sure...classes are more helpful to group them and unless you have any css specifics per button ID isn't important. Most people when learning javascript want to use ID...simplest selectors , but realistically classes are more helpful

Comment: ok i deleted now the ID from all 3 buttons, but the code wont work anymore :/? So the ID needs to be there? Btw thx for helping me :)!

Comment: must be some other code then. Code in answer doesn't use ID of buttons, it does for the content

Comment: You had right it worked now, you are awesome :D! Just one more thing in my html code i have 3 div below the buttons. Those 3 div contain a ID attribute and a Class attribute. Can i replace the class attribute and put in the JS somehow? The class attribute makes the div not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

To shorten this bit of code:

```
$('#click-1a').click(function () {
  show('#showmore-1a');
});

$('#click-1b').click(function () {
  show('#showmore-1b');
});

$('#click-1c').click(function () {
  show('#showmore-1c');
});
```

Well, I could tell this:

```
$('[id^="click-"]').click(function () {
  show('#showmore-' + this.id.replace("click-", ""));
});
```